# Formatting documents with HTML3 and no CSS, for a modern webdev

Tags: html, legacy

HTML5 and CSS3 were already the standard when I started developing, so I have never used old-school HTML. I find myself trying to work with a legacy application which will not tolerate anything other than HTML3, and which refuses to honor even basic CSS like `border` and `margin`.

I have a page design which would be almost trivial in modern HTML5 and CSS. However, given the technological limitations, I feel like suddenly I've had might right arm cut off, and my left arm put in a cast, and then told to do pushups.

Can any old-school webdevs give me tips on how to achieve the effects of the following CSS properties with plain HTML3?

- `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` (Rounding the corners of a border and preventing content from spilling out of the rounded border)
- `float: right` and `clear: right` (for an image with text flowing around it)
- A gradient background
- `display: inline-block; vertical-align: text-top;` (See near the bottom of the mockup below)

Any good general resources for formatting documents with HTML3 would be appreciated as well. Even is you specifically put HTML3 in a search engine, it really only gives HTML5 results, so I'm not really even sure where to begin looking.

Here's a rough mockup of the layout I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Mockup]

Comment: It feels like designing emails, you need to code for 1999 PCs.  Have you tried plain using tables instead of your regular divs and more modern elements?

Comment: I'm trying to use a PDF generator called HTMLDOC actually. I have been made aware that tables are the primary mechanism for a lot of layout tasks, but I'm still not entirely sure how I'm going to handle the rounded border, floating images, etc... Things don't line up in a nice grid for me.